# Using class set value to access a list subset

Tags: python, list

The `testList` example represents list strings from a text file. The `compareList` represents a values list from a dictionary. I want to 'pull out' subsets of a string AFTER the match.

```
# Use a set result to print "fox here!"
testList = ['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'here!']
compareList = ['beige', 'black', 'brown']
foundList = []

result = set(testList) & set(compareList)
# <class 'set'> {'brown'}
```

How to use the `compareList` value 'brown' to print the remainder of the `testList` eg `['fox', 'here!']` From a resultant `foundList`

Comment: Why don't you want `'quick'` to be in the output?

Comment: @user2357112 Because they want the elements *after* the matching one.

Comment: What should happen if there are more than one matching values? Should it print everything after the first match or last match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of `brown` and then slice the rest of the list.

```
color = list(result)[0]
index = testList.index(color)
rest = testList[index+1:]
```

Comment: Thank you. There won't  be more than one matching value. In my real world situation the  `testList` members are address strings like '1 Short Street Suburb' The `compareList` are values from a street type dictionary eg 'Road, Street, Avenue' etc. So there will only be one match for each compare.

Comment: OK, as long as no one lives on Avenue Street.

Comment: Incidentally, there are two separate roads called "Street Road" in Pennsylvania.

Comment: @Dave If you're planning on using code like this to parse addresses, I think you're opening up a can of worms. You should probably search for existing libraries that already do it.

Comment: It's a specialized task using local data. I live in a small country where, to the best of my knowledge, no one has done this.